# If $z$ is inversely proportional to $x$ and $z=5$ when $x=7$, find the value of $x$ when $z=70$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $z$ is inversely proportional to $x$ and $z=5$ when $x=7$, find the value of $x$ when $z=70$.

Comment: This is a "do my homework" question

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It means that all we see is your question, with no context, no attempt to answer it, and no manners. This is a site for improving one's mathematical abilities, not for doing other people's homework. By all means, yes, ask for help if you're stuck, but let us know what you think and what you've done. That way, we can help you to answer similar questions yourself in future.

Comment: im trying to understand what people are doing as well not just blindly copying....

Comment: How are we supposed to know that if all you do is show us the question?

Comment: ok ok i'll say what i've already done next time  and some step i had already done but im not that sure so im afraid to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two numbers are inversely proportional it is defined as:

$$a =\frac{k}{b}$$

Where $a$ is inversely proportional to $b$, and $k$ is a constant.

Therefore, in this problem:

$$z =\frac{k}{x}$$

When $z = 5$, $x=7$, so we can use this to find $k$:

$$5 =\frac{k}{7},\ k = 35$$

So our equation now becomes:

$$z = \frac{35}{x}$$

When $z = 70$, we have to find the value of $x$:

$$70 = \frac{35}{x},\ x = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @linwei if you are content with the answer, feel free to upvote/check so other users know it has been answered.